# Is there a way to simultaneously download multiple audio files in pytube?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, youtube, pytube

I have made a youtube to mp3 app in python using pytube. I wanted to be able to download multiple songs at once, as in add them to a queue of some sort and all items in it would begin to download together.

Comment: What OS? If it's on Linux, save yourself the trouble and look at the `parallel` command. You can just run your script in parallel. You can also just use a for-loop in the shell (`for i in $(seq 100); do c=$(($c + 1)); if [ "$c" -gt "10" ]; then wait; fi; myscript --my-param foo &; done` will keep 10 of your script running in the background until all 100 have run)

Comment: @Gabe I'm on windows. Also I'm looking for code I can use in an editor as the program has a UI.